# JavaScript onClick only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following onClick code only works in Chrome. In Opera and Firefox the button only hides on click without opening the link.

```
 <div>
    <button>
    <a  onClick="window.open('http://www.google.ro', 'sharer',
       'toolbar=0,status=0,width=500,height=325');" 
       href="javascript: void(0)"><img src=""/></a>
    </button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();

})
});//]]>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/trefu/TVJWD/154/)

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why don't you move the `onclick` code into the `.click()` event handler itself?

Comment: Why do you have an anchor inside a `button`?

Comment: Because Chrome is awesome...?

Comment: `button`s may not have interactive (like your `a` tag) children. Try attaching the `onclick` handler to your `button` or even better, attach it via `$` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the extra markup.. try this

Also look at the excellent answer given by dystroy

```
<img data-href="http://www.google.ro" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Futurosoft%20Icons%200.5.2/128x128/apps/vlc.png"/>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function(){
    $("img").click(function() {
      $(this).hide();
      window.open($(this).attr('data-href'), 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=500,height=325');
    });
  });
 </script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TVJWD/164/)

Comment: glad it worked for you :) Also always try making your code re-useable :) i try my best to do this :)

Comment: Can you help me with this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575184/show-hidden-download-box-after-user-shares-a-link I would appreciate any help :D

Comment: @InnaMarina if any of the answers helped you then please mark it as the correct answer.. sure i'll be glad to assist

Answer (score 5):

The `a` element is forbidden in a `button` element.

From [the W3.org on the button element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) :

> there must be no interactive content descendant.

Interactive contents are described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0). `a` is listed among them.

The idea is that the button handles the interaction. That's why browsers are allowed not to let descendants receive the events.

In your case, you just should bind the window opening action on the `button` element.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<a>` and bind `onClick` directly to the `<button>`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put the open method in the click function?

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    window.open('http://www.google.ro', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=500,height=325');
})
```

And whilst you are there, get rid of that `<a>` (See dystroy's answer):

```
<div>
    <button>
        <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Futurosoft%20Icons%200.5.2/128x128/apps/vlc.png"/>
    </button>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TVJWD/158/)

Comment: I'm glad, please remember to accept the answer that helped you reach your objective.

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head, but try this:

```
<div><input type="button"><a  onClick="window.open('http://www.google.ro', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=500,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)"><img src=""/></a></input></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not good to have `<a>` in the `<button>`

```
<button>
  <a  onClick="window.open('http://www.google.ro', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=500,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)"><img src=""/></a>
</button>
```

Try this instead remove the `<a>` tag and apply the `onclick()` event to button:

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://www.google.ro', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=500,height=325');"><img src=""/></button>
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TVJWD/161/)

Comment: Thank you! Can you help me with this too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575184/show-hidden-download-box-after-user-shares-a-link I would appreciate :D

Answer (score 0):

that a tag is messing it up, and chrome is awesome enough to fix it:)

Try this:

```
<div><button onClick="window.open('http://www.google.ro', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=500,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)"><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Futurosoft%20Icons%200.5.2/128x128/apps/vlc.png"/></button></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trefu/TVJWD/154/

Comment: When IE disregards standards, they're breaking the web... when Chrome does it, it's because it's so awesome.

Comment: i know i know, i was joking :)

Comment: hehehehehe.. chrome breaks standards and makes everything work.. IE stops things from working.. Chrome is awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the new window open in the JavaScript:-

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=500,height=325');
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

...and remove the JavaScript from the markup:-

```
<div><a href="http://www.google.ro"><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Futurosoft%20Icons%200.5.2/128x128/apps/vlc.png"/></a></div>
```

Keeping the JavaScript separate from the HTML is best practice as it will make maintenance and bug fixing easier for you.

Also you shouldn't be using a link within the form element. It should work fine without it:-
http://jsfiddle.net/drmonkeyninja/TVJWD/165/

Comment: Thank you! Can you help me with this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575184/show-hidden-download-box-after-user-shares-a-link I would appreciate

Answer (score 0):

bind the `onClick` event with button instead of link like the following..

```
<div><button onClick="window.open('http://www.google.ro', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=500,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)"><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Futurosoft%20Icons%200.5.2/128x128/apps/vlc.png"/></button></div>
```

and this will work.

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine :D Can you help me with this too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575184/show-hidden-download-box-after-user-shares-a-link I would appreciate