# Show hidden download box after user shares a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a hidden download box div appear after a visitor shares a link.I've tried here something http://jsfiddle.net/trefu/qNDJB/4/ but is not working. I don't know how to define FB so it can be called. Can someone help me?

```
 <div id='fb-root'></div>

<div id="download_box" style="display: none;">
    Download Box (whatever that means) goes here
</div>

  FB.init({appId: "437410746335629", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

  function callback(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        document.getElementById('download_box').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        alert('You must share your post before you can download.');
    }
}

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

Comment: `FB` is the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). Fair to assume you copy and pasted this and this `appId: "437410746335629"` is not yours?

Comment: I know how to create an appid, is mine, but i get some errors: API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application. Here is where i tried  http://wowvi.blogspot.ro/

Comment: `redirect_uri: 'YOUR URL HERE',` should be in your `obj` object, before `link`. [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Comment: I know but i don't want to redirect, i want when someone shares the link to reveal a hidden download box.

Answer (score 0):

on having a look at wowvi.blogspot.ro:

`var cc = '<iframe allowfullscreen='true' frameborder='0' height='410' src='embed.php?id=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcg8xscHkXM' width='640'></iframe>';`

Change this to

`var cc = "<iframe allowfullscreen='true' frameborder='0' height='410' src='embed.php?id=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcg8xscHkXM' width='640'></iframe>";`

You are using single quotes inside single quotes..

Comment: That's new and unrelated to the original bug. This error still exists: `Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

Comment: It matches the application domain url ...but still getting the error

Comment: @InnaMarina I see that its working on your site now.. mind sharing the fix?